# Testcafe: Ability to tell value of disableMultipleWindows inside of test?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that sometimes gets run with the command line flag `--disable-multiple-windows` and sometimes it doesn't. I would like the test to skip over a section if multiple windows are disabled. Is there an easy way to tell that within a test?

My best solution so far is something like the following

```
let disableMultipleWindows=true;
try{
await t.openWindow('www.google.com');
disableMultipleWindows=false
await t.closeWindow();
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

At present, disabling support for multiple browser windows is possible only for tests run scenarios. There is no access to the `--disable-multiple-windows` option within a test body. You can learn more about this option at [Disable Support for Multiple Windows](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows#disable-support-for-multiple-windows).

Could you please clarify your scenario of using the `--disable-multiple-windows` option? I think you can split your tests into different tests suites: with/without multiple browser windows.

Comment: Good to know. You're right, I can just create two tests, thought I could be a little tricky by having one test that behaves differently depending on whether multiple windows is allowed but that may be bad practice.